# how to check existing user in a database with Struts and Ajax

Tags: ajax, jsp, struts2

I want to verify if an email exists in my database before form submission:

```
<form  action="add" method="post">
  <input type="text"   name="user.email" />
  <input type="submit" value="Ajouter"   /> 
</form>
```

How can I use Ajax to check if the email exists already in the database before submitting?

Comment: Try struts2-jquery combination.

Comment: Same as with any other back end: make an Ajax call to an S2 action that looks in the DB for the email. What's the specific issue?

Comment: Please make sure to only include relevant code/markup in the question, it makes thinking about things much easier.

Comment: @Dave Newton: Or you can submit and check server-side if the email exists. If so, then return a relevant response. Is that bad practice?

Comment: @tom It's not a "bad practice", it's just not what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Validate() method when you extends the ActionSupport calls in your Controller ; then you check your email and return an ActionFieldError if it dosent' exist. 
it's simple:

```
public void validate() {

         if(!emailExist(this.email)){

         addFieldError(email, "Email already exist;You must choose another one"); }

    }
```

That assumes that you have a field with the name ="email" and a function that check mail existence called emailExist(String mail)

Comment: did anyone have an example so that it can be more clear !! Thanks

Comment: you can check the comment i edited it,and please don't forget to make a +1

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, which was how to check if the email exists before submitting the form.

Comment: it's a solution and i didn't say it's an AJAX solution

Answer (score 0):

If you really want ajax validation , you can use [Struts2 jQuery Plugin](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/S2PLUGINS/2012/07/11/Struts2+jQuery+Plugin+-+Version+3.3.2) and you instead of :

```
<s:submit />
```

you make something like this:

```
<sj:submit 
            targets="result" 
            button="true" 
            validate="true" 
            value="AJAX Submit" 
            indicator="indicator"
            />
```